# Добавление строк в секции вниз таблицы с анимацией

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Как добавить строки в секции таблицы? Есть вот такой код

`NSInteger rowIndex = [dictID allValues].count;
NSInteger setcionIndex = arraySection.count;
[weakSelf.tableView beginUpdates];
[weakSelf.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:setcionIndex]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[weakSelf.tableView endUpdates];`
Он выдает мне ошибку 'attempt to insert row 3 into section 2, but there are only 2 sections after the update'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю ты пытаешься дописать ряд к последней секции, тогда нужно просто выбрать правильную секцию.

```
NSInteger setcionIndex = arraySection.count - 1;
```

Если ты хочешь добавить секцию, тогда нужно также добавить секцию

```
[weakSelf.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:arraySection.count] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Код добавления и анимации правильный, но после `[weakSelf.tableView beginUpdates];` так же нужено обновить datasource, так как в момент `[weakSelf.tableView endUpdates];` ось снова вызовет `numberOfSectionsInTableView` и все `numberOfRowsInSection` и она ожидает, что теперь эти методы вернут данные, содержащие уже строки, которые ты добавил.

Comment: Не могу понять обновление datasource. Засунуть парсинг данных после `[weakSelf.tableView beginUpdates]`? Сейчас парсинг выполняется до. Сделал как ты посоветовал, все равно вылазит такая же ошибка, наверно из-за обновления datasource.

Comment: Под обновлением datasource понимается обновление тех данных, которые испольщуются для наполнения таблицы, да, это обновление можно сделать до, но классчески, если есть begin/endUpdates, то датасорс модифицируется внутри, параллельно с таблицей, но если апдейты таблицы идут сразу после обновления датасорса в том же методе - можно не заморачиваться. Важно - чтобы обновления датасорса в точности совпадали с командами обновления таблицы, то есть ряды добавлялись/удалялись в соответствующие секции, то же самое с секциями. Покажешь как выглядит датасорс? мне не понятно, откуда появляется rowIndex

Comment: `[responseObject[@"filmsData"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) { [array addObject:obj[@"id"]]; [dictID setValue:array forKey:[KSDate convertYandexDateToStringDate:responseObject[@"date"]]]; }];` парсю данные от ответа с сервера. dictID словарь. Всё это выполняется в блоке AFHTTPSessionManager когда делаю get-запрос.

Comment: А numberOfSectionsInTableView и numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: Просто вижу, что arraySection не используется при этом обновлении вообще

Comment: Вот я тоже так думаю, но пока не понимаю как его обновить. `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return arraySection.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *sectionTitle = arraySection[section];
    NSArray *array = dictID[sectionTitle];
    return array.count;}`

Comment: Используется после enumerateObjectsUsingBlock, я забыл его сюда вписать `arraySection = [dictID allKeys];`

Comment: Короче я примерно понял, что ты хочешь сделать, конечно, тут надо комплексно всё решать и писать правильно, но вроде чтобы починить твой код нужно во первый вместо `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` просто добавить секцию `insertSections` (так как в ней может много общектов вообще быть). А во вторых - по окончании enumerateObjectsUsingBlock в arraySection добавить ещё одну секцию, которая как я поинмаю будет называться `[KSDate convertYandexDateToStringDate:responseObject[@"date"]]`.

Comment: Решил вопрос все работает, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Количество ячеек должно совпадать с тем, что возвращается в методе datasource. Иначе произойдет падение. Смотрите где у Вас не совпадает. Или напишите больше кода.